# How to configure emacs.app to use git within *shell* for git on OSX

Tags: git, emacs

I'm using emacs.app 23.1.1 on OsX and trying to use git within a *shell*.
When I use a command like `git log-p`, I get

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
```

I also get something similar with `git commit` and I'm forced to use `git commit -m`.

How can I configure `emacs.app` so this works within its *shell*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you at least configure your git editor to be emacs? (as illustrated both in the [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch7-1.html) and in [Community Git book](http://book.git-scm.com/5_customizing_git.html))

```
git config -–global core.editor emacs
```

Because then, '`vi`' should never be called.

Comment: Looks like i need to delve into the book. Getting: emacs: Terminal type "dumb" is not powerful enough to run Emacs.
It lacks the ability to position the cursor.
If that is not the actual type of terminal you have,
use the Bourne shell command `TERM=... export TERM' (C-shell:
`setenv TERM ...') to specify the correct type.  It may be necessary
to do `unset TERMINFO' (C-shell: `unsetenv TERMINFO') as well.
error: There was a problem with the editor 'emacs'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Comment: @hiheelhottie: did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116560 ?

Comment: git config --global core.editor emacsclient 
did the trick with (server-start) in my init emacs file.  Save and then C-x C-# to close the buffer window to get back to git cmd line.

Answer (score 5):

Does this work for you?

```
M-x term
```

See [the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html) (it provides a more complete terminal emulation than just <kbd>M-x shell</kbd>).

Comment: I get further with git commit.  It seems to open up vi.  When I wq vi, I get

Comment: ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 10L, 281C written
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Comment: Is there a way to make the editor emacs and any other tips on how to get this to work?  Thanks.

Comment: @hiheelhottie Is the shell you're using a shell inside Emacs? (that's what I first thought) Or is it a different terminal?

Answer (score 4):

The `git log` command (stupidly, IMHO) by default pushes everything through a "pager".  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260947/git-log-output-messed-up#answer-2262611) for how to disable this.

Similarly, `git help` apparently simply invokes `man`, so you might try:

```
MANPAGER=cat git help log
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `GIT_PAGER` environment variable to `/bin/cat`

For Bash, add to `.bashrc`:

`export GIT_PAGER=/bin/cat`

Answer (score 1):

*shell* is a dumb terminal, so you're not going to get very far. I second Trey Jackson's recommendation of `M-x term`. At that point, you're still likely to have problems: the term info for the eterm-color is not typically installed. As a temporary fix you can try

```
mkdir ~/.terminfo/65;
cp /Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/e/eterm-color ~/.terminfo/65/
```

to get the copy that emacs.app brought along (assuming you have emacs.app installed through MacPorts - adjust the path as needed). If all goes well, then you can consider setting things up in the global term info 'database'.

Also: If you're running the shell in emacs and you set the editor to emacs, you'll end up trying to load emacs inside the shell inside emacs. That's bound to be a headache. Take a look at emacs server and/or daemon mode.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer suggesting **M-x term:…** if you are going to go into term **mode** instead of **shell mode**, make sure you are **inline mode** so it behaves more like your normal **emacs buffer(C-c C-j)**.  If already inline mode, then this will do nothing.  To switch between: **line mode (C-c C-j)** and **char mode (C-c C-k)** for term mode.  Also, you may want to try **ansi-term (M-x ansi-term)** instead of just term.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after installing something. My TERM was getting set to 'xterm-256color'. Changing this to 'xterm-color' in my ~/.bash_profile resolved the issue. Just add:

```
export TERM="xterm-color"
```